# Select multiple cookies for deletion in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, selection

I can search for my cookies in Chrome with:

```
chrome://settings/siteData?search=cookies
```

However, that only allows me to delete one at at time. Is there a way to select a number of cookies at the same time (without having to do a sub-search) and then delete them?

Comment: How can you even select the cookies without clicking on them once or typing their name? It's just one click on the trashcan icon and any cookie's deleted anyway, or first typing in the "Search Cookies" box to select some. Clicking the trash can once to delete would be faster & easier than a "click to select" then delete anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The current Chrome(Chromium) 63 has a "Search Cookies" box in the top right, where you can type in whatever cookies you want to only see, and below it shows a "REMOVE ALL SHOWN" to erase all those cookies at once:

[image]

---

If your version doesn't have the search box (you should probably upgrade) you could try an extension to manage cookies, [there appears to be dozens that change frequently, so a search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/manage%20cookies?hl=en-US&_category=extensions) & checking current reviews & trying out some might be another solution. There should be one that could auto-delete certain cookies, or you could just use the built-in blocklists & allow lists too.

Comment: That's a good answer, but I was hoping not to have to do a sub search. I just want to scroll down the list, collect the cookies I don't want and delete them in one go.

Answer (score 0):

This is something long overdue. I don't want to delete ALL of my cookies. Cookies are useful when applied properly and that's why they exist in the first place. But now there are thousands on this machine that I built 2 months ago. I don't want to delete MS office, Amazon, or the regularly used sites. There are about 50 I want to keep. The method of deleting batches based on search is only a tiny bit better than the one at a time approach. What I WANT is to be able to SELECT ALL, then DESELECT the ones I want to keep. In less than 5 minutes it would look just as I want it. Building it into the browser shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1143819)